# Extract value from previous row based on a condition

Tags: r, data-analysis, data-cleaning

I have a dataset that looks as follows:

```
data <- tribble(
  ~Date, ~Ticker, ~Close, ~Open,
  "1989-09-11","COND",77.3292,77.3292,
  "1989-09-12","COND",77.4435,77.4435,
  "1989-09-13","COND",76.3118,76.3118,
  "1989-09-14","COND",75.5309,75.6344,
  "1989-09-15","COND",75.6598,75.4675)
```

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  Date       Ticker Close  Open
  <chr>      <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 1989-09-11 COND    77.3  77.3
2 1989-09-12 COND    77.4  77.4
3 1989-09-13 COND    76.3  76.3
4 1989-09-14 COND    75.5  75.6
5 1989-09-15 COND    75.7  75.5
```

The issue with it is that until a certain date, the closing price is identical with the opening price. What I'm trying to do is writing a function that checks if the opening and closing price are the same, and if that's the case, it replaces the opening price with the closing price from the previous row. If applied to the above data, it would transform the data as follows:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  Date       Ticker Close  Open
  <chr>      <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 1989-09-11 COND    77.3  NA
2 1989-09-12 COND    77.4  77.3
3 1989-09-13 COND    76.3  77.4
4 1989-09-14 COND    75.5  75.6
5 1989-09-15 COND    75.7  75.5
```

I tried to do it with an if statement, but I'm running into problems as soon as I try to get the value from the previous row in the "Close" column to the current "Open" value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `dplyr`, it's a simple `mutate` with `lag`.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  mutate(Open = if_else(Open == Close, lag(Close), Open))
## A tibble: 5 x 4
#  Date       Ticker Close  Open
#  <chr>      <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
#1 1989-09-11 COND    77.3  NA  
#2 1989-09-12 COND    77.4  77.3
#3 1989-09-13 COND    76.3  77.4
#4 1989-09-14 COND    75.5  75.6
#5 1989-09-15 COND    75.7  75.5
```